# TweetDeck Column Content Filter

Tags: macos, twitter

I am using TweetDeck 2.5.3 on Mac downloaded from the Mac App Store. I want to filter the content in a column but cannot find the filter. When I click the Edit link on the column I only see options for Notifications. Where is the column content filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. There is no explicit way to enter a column search in TweetDeck. When searching from the main search bar at the top of the window, you must type the Return / Enter key to bring up the custom Add Column feature. Typing in the search field will display auto suggested results in two sections, one at the top and one at the bottom. The top section contains search terms and the bottom section contains matched users. You must select from the top section a search term to get te Add Column feature. Selecting a user from the bottom section displays the user profile. I used Mac OS X for this but it may work the same on Windows.